# I can SSH to one instance via bastion, but not to a second instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I supposed to add the ssh key and then ssh to the AWS instance using a jumphost in 2 operations
So, first adding the key

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/<key-file>.pem
```

Then ssh to jumphost

```
ssh -A ec2-user@jumphost
```

And then from jumphost to instance

```
ssh ec2-user@<private IP>
```

This works for one instance but does not work for another instance - cannot ssh to this instance from a jumphost.

What instance setting can prevent me  to do ssh?

The output of ssh -v ec2-user@

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <private ip>[<private ip>] port 22
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting while trying to login to second server?

Comment: @Alex try to telnet for the host to the port 22, if you are able to connect then there is no issue with SG rule/Firewall and check .pem permission as well. Paste the output of ssh -v

Comment: No error, just stuck

Comment: Looks like port 22 is not opened. Open the port 22 for the jumpbox IP in the instance SG

Comment: paste the output of telnet <privateip> 22

Comment: If it is not firewall, are both the machines in same vpc/subnet? If it is in different vpcs make sure peering exists and firewall/NACL rules are allowed

Comment: LogicIO, your comment helped, if you put this into answer I will approve. Needed to check vpc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was pointed by the user LogicIO.  Somehow, one instance was moved to the different VPC and therefore the jumphost (bastion) and the instance appeared on the different VPC's, so connection stopped working.  I needed a different jumphost.

Answer (score 3):

There are different causes of this issue.

1. Check the security group of the ec2 instance you are connecting from the jump host / bastion if port 22 is open. If it's not open, add the rule. You can verify this if you telnet the destination server on port 22 form the jump host / bastion. command: telnet *destinationip* 22
2. if the above doesn't work, check if the ec2 instance you are connecting is in a **running** state with **2/2 checks passed**. This will make sure that both network and operating system are functional.
3. if the above doesn't work, check if your Network Access List (NACLs) are allowing the inbound and outbound traffic. The default setting allows the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the the firewall is setup correctly! That is mandatory in AWS console when you setup your new instance. My guess is a wrong default was selected.

Comment: Please, explain in terms of instance settings.  What can be the difference between 2 instances

Comment: Alex: you should see the selected firewall profile in the aws console for both instances.

Comment: I do not see firewalls, I see security groups

Comment: i meant security groups. didn't use aws in a while and forgot the amazon-speach.